# MySQL Server Disappeared

Tags: mysql, database-design, connections

I haven't used my `MySQL` local server in over a year.  Today I tried to get in to it, and the server seems to have just vanished.  I've been searching a troubleshooting all day and have gotten nowhere.  I have gotten several different error messages trying several different attempts to fix/uninstall/reinstall the server, so here are a couple:

When attempting to download and install the most recent version of the server from the MySQL webpage:

> Service MySQL56 was not found on computer '.'

When I try to test the connection in the MySQL Workbench:

> Failed to connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root.  Can't
>   connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)

And when I try to open my previously-established local server, I get directed to the "Administration" tab.  On the left, in the "Navigator" pane, I went to the "Startup/Shutdown" tab.  It said that "The database server instance is stopped" so I hit the button that said "Start Server".  It gave me these messages in the console:

> Trying to connect to MySQL...  Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   '127.0.0.1' (10061) (2003)  Assuming server is not running

This may be attributable to my relatively small base of knowledge in regards to `MySQL`, but I just can't figure out what's wrong.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

These things don't just grow legs and walk away.  It's likely something has gone wrong at some point in time, or something crucial has been removed.  Do you know where the logs originally were located at?  You're very likely to have a much better message than what you're getting now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to locate my.cnf or my.ini file. You will see config items and importantly datadir. See if that location exists.
Default [installation layouts are explained here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/installation-layouts.html) for you to look as well.

You can search your computer for *.ibd/*.myd/*.frm files and look into respective folders.

As far as you can find the datadir (data) you should be ok to reinstall MySQL!
(Yes there are some version differences issues but let's find out mysql data first)